# cron job node.js: job is repeating infinitely

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron

Trying to achive cron-jobs in my node.js application using this package.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule

here i am running a cronjob on a specific date and time.

```
schedule.scheduleJob(new Date(date), function(){
                        console.log('The world is going to end today.');
                    });
```

From their doc

> > Say you very specifically want a function to execute at 5:30am on
> >     December 21, 2012. Remember - in JavaScript - 0 - January, 11 -
> >     December.  the date should be look like this
> >      var date = new Date(2012, 11, 21, 5, 30, 0);

and i am generating cron job  `date` from a unix timestamp using moment.

```
   let date = moment.unix(dateInUTC).format('YYYY-M-DD-H-mm-s').split('-');
   date[1]  = date[1]-1;
   return date.toString();
```

sample output of the above date

```
UNIX  time 1516196220
Converted date 2018,0,17,19,07,0
```

everything works fine but the cron job runs infinitely ie my console look like this

```
 console.log('The world is going to end today.');
 console.log('The world is going to end today.');
 console.log('The world is going to end today.');
 console.log('The world is going to end today.');
 -------------------------------
-------------------------------
 endless
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your date won't end up in the correct format:

```
let date = moment.unix(dateInUTC).format('YYYY-M-DD-H-mm-s').split('-');
date[1]  = date[1]-1;
return date.toString();
```

So, `date` is an array, and you're calling `.toString()`. This will end up with something like the following:

```
'10,20,30,40,50'
```

This isn't in a parseable form by the `Date` constructor, which expects it in ISO8601 format.

`moment` is already emitting a `Date` value for the timestamp that you specified; can you just use that directly?

Comment: i can't use it directly bcz the month index should start with zero eg:0 - January, 11 - December  thats why i am using split method

Comment: Is that not managed by `moment`? If not, it's not emitting the dates correctly.

Comment: In that case, you'll need to parse it in Moment, then reconstruct the date properly (i.e. pass in the components separately into the `Date()` constructor).

Comment: yes i am doing on that way see my first code part `new Date(date)`

Comment: But `date` is generated from `return date.toString();`. You're calling `.toString()` on an array, which will print out a string like in my answer, which won't be recognised by the constructor. You need to pass the components _separately_ to the `Date` constructor

Comment: So I need to pass it in array?? Can you give an example